# Dynamic kerning or tracking of fonts in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there was a way to change the kerning of a font letter using Javascript. I was also wondering if it could be done dynamically, as I know there's a manual way of doing it.

What I mean is is there a way to set a range of sizes that could be dynamically attached to margin-left.

From the code below, I want for eg, the "H" to have a margin-left value of 0rem, the"o" to have a margin-left of -0.095rem, and so on.

```
var a = document.getElementById("x");

window.onload = function(){
let sizes = ['0', '-0.095', '-0,07', '4'];
let letters = ['H', 'o', 'm', 'e']; 
for(var i=0; i< letters.length; i++){
        a.innerHTML += letters[i]
        a.setAttribute('style', 'margin-left:'+sizes[1]+"rem")
    }
}
```

The above code doesnt produce the desired results, but it will give you an idea of what I mean. Is there a way? Hope its clear for everyone...

++++Updated the code++++

Comment: It is not very clear what is expected. Why do you treat `letters` as a 2 dimensions array when it ' s only 1 dimension ? Why do you only use the 1 index in `sizes[1]` ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to make use of all the indexes...I know the code is confusing...I want the letter "H" to have a margin-left value of 0rem, "o" to have a value of -0.095rem... this'll just make the look of the word "Home" more pleasing...

Comment: But you can't set a margin value for each letter, a margin must be set for a whole html element. Eventually you could put each letter in a span and set a margin  for each span.

Comment: Yes, tried that. That is a long task to do...just thought there'd be an easier way...

Comment: @Transformers no there is no other way other than wrapping each letter with a span with a custom class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of implementation. I just changed your size values to make them more visible at render

```js
const sizes = ['0rem', '1rem', '1.3rem', '4rem'];

const letters = ['H', 'o', 'm', 'e'];

letters.forEach((letter, index) => {
  const span = document.createElement("span");
  span.textContent = letter;
  span.style.marginLeft = sizes[index];
  document.body.appendChild(span);
});
```